# How to make this page responsive for all resolutions?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, width

I'm new and I'm having a problem--this page is not responsive for 1366, and 1280 resolutions on PC, on 1920, and on mobile it's perfect. May you please help me with this one?

I tried adding contain on object-fit, but that didn't help me, I think the problem is with the width but I can't figure out how to solve this properly without ruining it on 1920 resolution and mobile phone.

Resolution 1366

[image]

```css
.container1 {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container1>div {
  padding: 0px 5px;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 325px;
}

.container1 div img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.zgrade {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 745px;
  min-width: 428px;
}

.zgradeimg {
  width: 500px;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.zgrade:hover img {
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

@media screen and (max-width: 780px) {
  .container1 {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .container1>div {
    padding: 10px 5px;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container1">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="zgrade">
      <a href="zgradaA.html">
        <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" /></a>
    </div>

    <br>
    <div class="zgrade"><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="p-6"></div>

<div class="container1">
  <div class="row justify-content-center ">
    <div class="zgrade ">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/800" /></div>
    <br>

    <div class="zgrade"><img src="assets/img/szgrade/zgradaD.jpg" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please tag your Bootstrap version.

Comment: You should not be applying all that custom CSS to Bootstrap. Please review the docs so you're aware of what it provides, then work _with_ the library, not against it. Then, revise your post to describe what behavior you want. "Responsive" isn't a description. It's a very general term for changing behavior based on conditions.

Comment: You also don't need vendor prefixes for the [transition](https://caniuse.com/mdn-css_properties_transition) or [transform](https://caniuse.com/transforms2d) properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed Row code from the container and it's working. :) They are only used for containing columns. I don't have columns so I tried removing the row class and everything is cool right now. I hope that this will stay like this :)